# I'm working on a project in Laravel and I'm facing an Undefined variable $post error in post-card.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-8

**post.blade.php
The main post file**

```
<main class="max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-6 lg:mt-20 space-y-6">

    <x-post-featured-card :post="$posts[0]" />

    <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2">
        @foreach ($posts->skip(1) as $post)
          <x-post-card :post="$post" />
        @endforeach
    </div>

</main>
```

**post-card.blade.php
This file is throwing the undefined variable $post error**

```
<div class="mt-4">
   <h1 class="text-3xl">
      {{ $post->title }}
   </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@props(['post'])
@foreach($posts as $post)

    <div class="mt-4">
       <h1 class="text-3xl">
          {{ $post->title }}
       </h1>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Please add an explanaton to your answer, code-only answers are not considered to be of high quality, as they do not clarify how and why is the code solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few steps

1. change the name of the file of post-card.blade.php
2. remove the other commented component from the file post-card.blade.php if have any
3. use props in the file that give error, like @props(['post'])